# How to change highlight color of windows on taskbar in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: kde, themes, appearance, kde5, plasma-5

Currently windows on panel's taskbar panel highlighted by blue by default, how could I change that color without changing the entire theme (can't find).

[image]

Comment: Your title mentions "minimized" but the body of your question seems to indicate you mean "maximized". Could you please clarify?

Comment: @DK Bose I edited question, I hope it's better now, if not feel free to edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various colors can be changed via `System Settings`.

- Under `Workspace Theme`, make a note of the themes that are active in `Look and Feel` and `Desktop Theme`.
- Go back to the opening screen of `System Settings` and click on `Colors`.
- Under `Application Color Scheme`, click on the name of the scheme you have as active in `Look and Feel`.
- Below the list of themes, click `Edit Scheme`.
- Ensuring that you haven't changed the `Color set` from `Common Colors`, scroll down till you come to `Hover Decoration`.
- Click on the existing color to open a color chooser palette. Here, select the color you want and click `Okay`.
- Click `Apply` and `Save`. At this point, **to avoid overwriting the original scheme**, give another name for your scheme.
- Close the window.
- Now, click on the scheme you created and then click `Apply` once again. That's important!

Note that:

- you haven't really changed the entire scheme. Your changes are stored in a small file in `~/.local/share/color-schemes` with the scheme name you gave earlier and a `.color` suffix.
- more than one visual aspect may be affected by the change you make. It will **not** be limited to just the taskbar.

As you get more familiar with things you can make many more changes to suit your visual needs.

[image: Changing colors - 1]

[image: Changigng colors -2]

Answer (score 2):

Please accept this updated answer for a newer version of KDE, I'm not sure from which version it started, but this applies to KDE Plasma 5.18.5 (which I'm running), via GUI:

1. There's now a `Colors` section in `System Settings` - go there.

   To find it:

   - Go to to `System Settings` > `Apperance` > `Colors`

   Or

   - Search in `System Settings for "Colors".
2. Highlight (with mouseover) your current color scheme. An edit button will appear (if you hover on it it'll say "Edit Color Scheme")
3. Click on the edit button. It'll open up the `KColorSchemeEditor` color scheme editor.
4. Make sure you're in the Colors tab (should be the default tab opened).
5. Scroll to look for "Hover Decoration" and then click on the color box.
6. A color selection tool should appear. Select your desired color.
7. Click on `OK` - it should auto-close the color selecton tool
8. In `KColorSchemeEditor` click on the `Apply` button. It shouldn't auto-close the window but you can close it manually by clicking on the `Close` buton.
9. Then, back in `Colors`, click on the `Apply` button. Again, it won't auto-close the indow, but you can close it manually by clicking on the close button.